# KOMA-script's beforeskip is not used when previous section is empty

Tags: koma-script

Bonjour, I am posting because I am truly at my wits end. The following MWE illustrates my challenge. I want a consistent spacing in between section, with or without text in them. How can I force the use of \beforeskip for each sections and subsections ? Any ideas ?

[image]

```
% Created 2022-03-03 Thu 18:07
% Intended LaTeX compiler: pdflatex
\documentclass[a5paper,BCOR=0mm,DIV=30,10pt]{scrartcl}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=10.0pt,afterskip=1pt]{section} 
\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=5.0pt,afterskip=1pt]{subsection}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\section*{Section}
\subsection*{Subsection does not follow beforeskip} 
\subsection*{Subsection does not follow beforeskip} 
\subsection*{Subsection does not follow beforeskip}  
test

\subsection*{Subsection  follows beforeskip} 
test

\subsection*{Subsection  follows beforeskip} 
test

\section*{Section follows beforeskip}
\subsection*{Subsection does not follow beforeskip} 
\subsection*{Subsection does not follow beforeskip} 
\section*{Section does not follows beforeskip}
\subsection*{Subsection does not follow beforeskip} 
test

\subsection*{Subsection  follows beforeskip} 
test

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks @DavidCarlisle, I orginally set it as \baselineskips, switched to ex for the sake of debugging. Any suggestion of a better unit ?

Comment: OK, I changed it to pt and will update my post accordingly, the core issue remains as we could expect. 
As for your other comments, the issue is precisely that I do not get the larget vspace at all. The space I expect are that beforeskip is applied consistenly as per the documentation of KOMA-script and I cannot find the exception mentioned anywhere in the KOMA-script doc.

Comment: hmm I don't really use Koma-script much but the manual here says _When redeﬁning a command, the key  style, afterskip, beforeskip, and level are mandatory. The keys
afterindent,font and indent are recommended._ You seem to be missing some mandatory entries

Comment: Indeed, I missed that thanks a lot! Adding them correctly doesn't change the behavior sadly.

Comment: sorry then I give up, someone who knows the koma code better should be able to trace (I agree the spacings are not what I'd expect from addvspace combination of the skips here)  I deleted earlier comments

Comment: Thank you for your input :). I will update if I find a solution.

Comment: There is the same vertical spacing after a heading, whether it is followed by text or a heading. This is the same behavior as for standard classes (even if you use package `titlesec`). So the only solution for your challenge seems to be using an equal value for `beforeskip` and `afterskip` for all related section levels.

Comment: I am confused by your comment, there is probably something I do not understand. I am not complaining about afterskip but beforeskip. I am interested by the preceding the Section not following.

Answer (score 2):

`beforeskip` is only used if the switch `\if@nobreak` is false: (I use larger values to make the difference more pronounced):

```
\documentclass[a5paper,10pt]{scrartcl}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=30.0pt,afterskip=1pt]{section}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=25.0pt,afterskip=1pt]{subsection}
\begin{document}
\section{A}
\subsection{B}
\subsection{B}

\section{A}
\makeatletter \@nobreakfalse\makeatother
\subsection{B}
\makeatletter \@nobreakfalse\makeatother
\subsection{B}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This is not different to the handling in the standard classes.

Normally that is the behaviour you want, it looks much better if there is not so much space between two sectioning commands directly following each other. If you really want an uniform spacing, set the beforeskip to zero and use a strut instead (but be aware that it will also be used at the top of a page):

```
\documentclass[a5paper,10pt]{scrartcl}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=10.0pt,afterskip=1pt]{section}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=-1sp,afterskip=1pt]{subsection}
\addtokomafont{subsection}{\rule{0pt}{25pt}}
\begin{document}
\section{A}
\subsection{B}
\subsection{B}
text
\subsection{B}
```

\end{document}

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much ! I I understand your point on the "better look" but I guess my use-case is a little out of the ordinary. Indeed, I am exporting the section titles from org-mode . When they are marked as TODOs in the org-mode format, I want to see them more as a list with a few additional notes when needed . \\

 By "using a strut", do you mean adding "\addtokomafont{subsection}{\rule{0pt}{25pt}}". What is a strut in that context ?

Comment: I didn't know about struts either. But https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Rules_and_Struts is clear:
"A special case is a rule with no width but a certain height. In professional typesetting, this is called a strut. It is used to guarantee that an element on a page has a certain minimal height. You could use it in a tabular environment or in boxes to make sure a row has a certain minimum height."