# Adjust vertical spacing after section title heading and before tcolorbox environment

Tags: spacing, sectioning, koma-script, tcolorbox, vertical-spacing

How can I adjust the vertical spacing after the section heading and before the `tcolorbox` environment?

Here's my MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{mathtools, amsthm, amssymb} % Math packages
\usepackage[warnings-off={mathtools-colon,mathtools-overbracket}]{unicode-math} % Math fonts
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox} % Colored boxes

% Heading font size
\setkomafont{chapter}{\huge}
\setkomafont{section}{\LARGE}

% Spacing
\renewcommand*{\chapterheadstartvskip}{\vspace*{0cm}}
\renewcommand*{\chapterheadendvskip}{\vspace*{\baselineskip}}
\RedeclareSectionCommands[
  beforeskip=-.5\baselineskip,
  afterskip=.5\baselineskip
]{section}

% Custom tcolorbox environment
\newtcolorbox{mybox}[1][]{colback=black!5!white,colframe=black,boxrule=1pt,arc=0mm,#1}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Limits}
\section{Provisional Definition of the  Limit of a Function}

\begin{mybox}[before skip=2ex, after skip=4ex,boxsep=0pt]
    The function \(f\) approaches the limit \(L\) near \(c\), if we can make \(f(x)\) as close as we like to \(L\) by requiring that \(x\) be sufficiently close to, but unequal to, \(c\).
\end{mybox}

\end{document}
```

It seems that even if I adjust the `before skip` value to any value, it doesn't seem to affect the vertical spacing ***unless*** I add a text or a blank space `\`  in between, like this:

[image]

```
\section{Provisional Definition of the  Limit of a Function}
\
\begin{mybox}[before skip=2ex, after skip=4ex,boxsep=0pt]
    The function \(f\) approaches the limit \(L\) near \(c\), if we can make \(f(x)\) as close as we like to \(L\) by requiring that \(x\) be sufficiently close to, but unequal to, \(c\).
\end{mybox}
```

Is the inserted blank space `\`  absolutely necessary? Thank you.

Comment: This sounds like a job for the parameters that govern the spacing parameters of `\section` (and `\subsection`, etc.), rather than the parameters that govern the spacing around a `tcolorbox`. The argument of your sample `\section` directive doesn't contain a single character with a descender component. (A descender is the part of a character -- such as `j`, `p`, `q`, and `y` -- that protrudes below the baseline.) For an immediate fix, insert `\strut` at the very end of the argument of `\section`.

Comment: Do also ask yourself if the option `afterskip=0.5\baselineskip` of `\RedeclareSectionCommands[...]{section}` isn't just too stingy in general. E.g., give `afterskip=1\baselineskip` a try.

Comment: I see, after changing the `afterskip` value to `1\baselineskip` it does seem to look better. Thank you.

Comment: but what I still don't understand is why the `before skip` value doesn't apply

Comment: That's because the aboveskip is vertical-mode "glue" -- sorry for the TeX jargon; TeX discards "glue" automatically if it's adjacent to other glue. (This is actually highly desirable if a `mybox` environment occurs at the top of a page.) Inserting a space breaks this adjacency. I still think, though, that the main problem lies with the inadequate amount of whitespace below `\section`, not with the supposedly insufficient amount of whitespace above `mybox`.

Comment: Thanks! I've heard the term "glue" before but I'm not sure where to read more about it.

Comment: If you have access to Knuth's *TeXbook*, I suggest you study chapter 12, "Glue", pp. 69-83. That, or read Chapter 8, "Boxes and Glue", in Eijkhout's [TeX by Topic](https://ctan.org/pkg/texbytopic),

Comment: It could be a similar problem to https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/635984. Maybe `beforeskip` of the `tcolorbox` is only used if if the switch `\if@nobreak` is false.